# Flask TypeError: 'NoneType' Not Subscriptable

Tags: flask

I'm trying to create a database in Postman in order to store an email and password for a user login, and I have my flask app.py file all built out, but when I try to establish said database in Postman, I get the error:

```
File "C:\Users\cleve\Desktop\FINAL PROJECT\FP\flask\app.py", line 33, in add_user
    email = request.json['email']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Im not exactly sure what Im doing wrong (Im following a guide from school to build this out and changing some of the code around to suit the needs of my project,) but here is my app.py page in its entirety.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.sqlite')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(144), unique=False)

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password


class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('email', 'password')


user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)

@app.route('/user', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
  email = request.json['email']
  password = request.json['password']
  new_user = User(email, password)
  db.session.add(new_user)
  db.session.commit()
  user = User.query.get(new_user.id)
  return user_schema.jsonify(user)
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`request.json` is a shortcut for `request.get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)` and it returns `None` if you don't send `Content-Type: application/json` header which may be the issue here.

You can force Flask to parse JSON if you call `request.get_json(force=True)`, example:

```py
@app.route('/user', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
  json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
  email = json_data['email']
  password = json_data['password']
  new_user = User(email, password)
  db.session.add(new_user)
  db.session.commit()
  user = User.query.get(new_user.id)
  return user_schema.jsonify(user)
```

Comment: So I tried the change you were suggesting, and im now getting the error: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)</p>`